# Alternative of public setter methods

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

Given a class called AVLNode containing the node description of a tree,

```
template<typename T>
class AVLNode
{
 public:
    AVLNode(T, AVLNode<T>*, AVLNode<T>*, int);
    ~AVLNode();
    void setLeft(AVLNode<T>*);
    AVLNode<T>* getLeft() const;
    void setRight(AVLNode<T>*);
    AVLNode<T>* getRight() const;
    void setHeight(int);
    void setKey(const T& );
    int getHeight() const;
    const T& getKey() const;

  private:
    T key;
    AVLNode<T> *left;
    AVLNode<T> *right;
    int height;
  };
```

And the following rotation method inside a class AVLTree.

```
template<typename T>
AVLNode<T>* AVLTree<T>::rotateRight(AVLNode<T> *node1)
 {
   AVLNode<T> *node2 = node1->getLeft();
   AVLNode<T> *T2 = node2->getRight();

   // Perform rotation
   node2->setRight(node1);
   node1->setLeft(T2);

  // Update heights
   node1->setHeight(max(height(node1->getLeft()), height(node1->getRight()))+1);
   node2->setHeight(max(height(node2->getLeft()), height(node2->getRight()))+1);

  // Return new root
   return node2;
 }
```

Is there any way to set these without the help of public setter methods? That is can I achieve this with private methods or another technique so that the client code can't change the attributes (unless and until the operations are really required)? How can I maximize data-hiding and reduce coupling?

**Edit:** I don't want to use public setter methods. Is there any other way to manipulate (set) private attributes? i.e; How can AVLNode objects set their private attributes without using public setter methods?

Comment: It has been awhile since I wrote C++ but I believe the concept you are talking about is "friend". http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/friend.html

Comment: I am not thinking of using friend relationship. See the last part: 'Edit' of the question. The clear question is written there.

Comment: You ask if there is another way, then turn down the obvious answer. You want the setter to not be public, but you want a priviledged class to access it. That's a friend. The only other option is sub-classing which doesn't make sense in this context. You can also add validation code to the setter to make it "more safe". I think you are being overly cautious. If someone adds code that is "malicious" then they break the code, that is there problem

Comment: thanks @Spidy , yeah i am going to use friend. It suits the best here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some container called AVLTree or something like that.

If so, I would define a class:

```
template <typename T>
class AVLNode
{
  protected:   
    T key;
    AVLNode<T>* left;
    AVLNode<T>* right;
    int height;

  public:
    AVLNode<T>* getRight() const { return right: }
    AVLNode<T>* getLeft()  const { return left;  }
};

template <typename T>
class WritableAVLNode : public AVLNode<T>
{
   public:
      void setRight(AVLNode<T>* right) { AVLNode<T>::right = right; }
      void setLeft(AVLNode<T>* left)   { AVLNode<T>::left = left; }
};
```

All the inner classes will work with WritableAVLNode but the methods will expose just the readonly version: AVLNode.

Comment: If I define struct AVLNode inside AVLTree, then also the problem is not solved. The AVLTree objects can access the attributes of AVLNode inside a public method by using a struct AVLNode type variable to access the left, right, key etc attributes. My concern is to curb the access over the attributes. See the last part ('Edit') part of the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `AVLTree` to have access to the private or protected members of the `AVLNode`, you could use a `friend` declaration. This would assume that the tree and the nodes are using the same type.

```
template <typename T>
class AVLNode
{
    friend class AVLTree<T>;    
};
```

Comment: I don't need AVLTree to be a friend class of AVLNode. I just want to know if any possible way is there which can help my application to have AVLNodes not modifying private attributes directly by using public setter methods. Simply speaking I don't want to use public setter methods. Is there any other way to manipulate (set) private attributes?

Comment: You can either make the member public, write a method that modifies the value or declare friends of the class. That's just how the language works. I don't see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yeah certainly I have done that - I have defined some public setter methods which modify the private attributes. For reference you can see the AVLNode class. But using public setter methods can make the program inconsistent as you can see in the 'rotateRight' method if any vulnerability is introduced, that vulnerable code can call any of the setter methods on any object available there [ considering the worst case scenario ]. That's why I am asking if any other way is possible there. I also don't know if there is any.